# jQuery echo's all HTML of PHP page

Tags: jquery

In my php page there is an HTML used outside the `<?php` tag, so when I use this jQuery code;

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type : "post",
        dataType: "html",
        url : "url.php",
        data : "to_uid="+to_uid+"&from_uid="+from_uid,
        cache: false,
        success : function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

It alerts the echo (either error or success messages) however it does echos all that HTML I used in that php page.

Is there any workaround I could echo only that error/success alerts and not the other HTML? I tried changing the `dataType` from `html` to `json` but it doesn't alert the error/success echo-s at all.

Please help.

Comment: AJAX returns all the output from the call, if you don't want some content then don't output it

Comment: The page is being parsed and returned as html, which is what php always does.  If you want to only return part of the page then you need to do that within the php.  You shouldn't fix this "issue" from client side.

Comment: @Archer You could, just filter the HTML content for what you want, it'd be better to have a separate call that returns just what you need though

Comment: Have your php only return the success/error content.

Comment: @JuanMendes Of course - you're right.  I should have said it would be wrong to do it at client-side (edited to suit - thanks).

Comment: @Kevin: No in addition to such error/success messages, my php page have numerous functions involved as well. forexample it shows some variables to be use on an HTML page, etc.

Juan: Can you please give me an example how I could parse HTML? Thank you

Comment: @user2854563 that's fine, but if you want you php to only return x, you have to make it only return x. there's nothing jquery can do about it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Can we use JSON as dataType? I think we can use, so does it has similar echo statement in PHP?

Comment: You can use json, however you would still have to have your php only return the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `url.php` set an array

```
$return = array();
if ( SOME CONDITION ) {
   $return['html'] = "<html> ... </html>";
   $return['message'] = 'Success Message';
   $return['stat'] = 'Success';
} else {
   $return['message'] = 'Fail Message';
   $return['stat'] = 'Failed';
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

and in your ajax

```
$.ajax(
{
    type : "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url : "url.php",
    data : "to_uid="+to_uid+"&from_uid="+from_uid,
    cache: false,
    success : function(response)
    {
        alert(response.message);
        if (response.stat == 'success') {
           do_some_thing(response.html);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Can we use it without using json as dataType?

Comment: you want to bring message from the php file? or just wanted to show alert about if ajax success or failed?

Comment: Yes, I want to bring error or success messages from PHP file.

Comment: in that case this is the only valid and proper method to do it easily, anything special with the dataType html?

Comment: No there is nothing special actually, I'll use your method as it seems a good one to follow on, Thank You Zeeshan bhai :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40270/discussion-between-zzlalani-and-user2854563)

Answer (score 0):

(Is there any workaround I could echo only that error/success alerts and not the other HTML?)

Yes, don't display it.

Try replacing this line :

```
success : function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        }
```

For that line :

```
 success : function()
        {
            alert('Success text to show');
        }
```

If that is what you meant, then you will be able to figure out by yourself how to process the error : message. See [jquery Ajax for more infos](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: @user2854563 change your alert... the response isn't something alert can handle... or do... `console.log(response)` and post the results in your question to help people figure out how to display what you want

Comment: @Milche: It only alerts what I entered in alert() function, and not from the echo statement from PHP file.

Comment: @user2854563 So i didn't get your question correctly.  User zzlalani seems to be leading you in a better path.